# Javadoc tag for showing doc of another method

Tags: java, javadoc

Is there a javadoc tag for showing the doc of another method? These are methods that simply relay the calls to other classes' methods. I'm looking for more than @see. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

If you use `{@link MyClass#myMethod(String, etc.)}`, the tooltip will show that as clickable and when clicked it will show the JavaDoc of `myMethod`. You can also add a description before the `}`.

Comment: Thanks - but i was looking for something that displays outright the javadoc of the other method.

Comment: @mtkilbay I don't know of something like that. For me it would be misleading. I imagine that it's a requirement that the actual method's Javadoc is shown, possibly pointing explicitly to another method, like `@see` or `@link`.

Answer (score 5):

There is no mechanism to include the documentation of any arbitrary method.

However, you can *inherit* documentation from the same method declared in the nearest superclass or interface, [using the tag {@inheritDoc}](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javadoc.html#CHDGJCHC) in the method comment, and/or in the @param, @return and @throws tag.

For example:

```
public class Foo {
  /** Implements the equals method for Foo objects.
   *  <p>Follows the contract specified by {@link java.lang.Object#equals(Object)}:</p>
   *
   * {@inheritDoc}
   *
   * @param obj {@inheritDoc}
   * @return {@inheritDoc}
   */
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
     ...
  }
  ...
}
```